# What do the terms interface class, static class, and abstract class mean in C++?

Tags: c++, class, abstract-class, static-class

Can anyone please explain me what is an interface class? Abstract Class? and Static Class? Please explain me with a simple example in C++. Since i am a beginner to C++.

Also, please give me some links where I can easily learn C++.

Comment: Static means just one instance, interface is class with abstract methods that should be overwrited by children

Comment: As I've said many, many, many times now, if you are new to C++, **[please pick up a good C++ book as recommended by the C++ community at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)**. You'll benefit more with resources written by C++ programmers who actually know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, an interface class is either a class of the interface layer or a class whose purpose is to create a contract between a caller and an implementation (usually by providing only purely virtual functions).

An abstract class is a class that has at least one purely virtual function.

A static class is a class that has only static member variables and static member functions.

If you have sufficient experience with some other programming language, read [The C++ Programming Language](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html). If not, you will have to go for a book that not only teaches C++, but also programming.